# Is the practise of standing on stones at election consigned to mythology and folklore?

Tags: norse, mythohistory, history, british

**Humblus**

I was reading up about legendary Danish kings when I came across a character named Humblus and a rather sensational claim is made at the bottom of the article, and that claim is that political nominees would stand on standing stones during election and the person with the tallest standing stone will likely get the votes.

[Humblus, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humblus)

> The ancients, when they were to choose a king, were wont to stand on stones planted in the ground, and to proclaim their votes, in order to foreshadow from the steadfastness of the stones that the deed would be lasting. By this ceremony Humble was elected king at his father's death, thus winning a novel favour from his country;

**Chronicon Lethrense**

Apparently the practise of standing on stones at election is discussed in a number of sources, including the Chronicon Lethrense.

However, the [Chronicon Lethrense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronicon_Lethrense) only records mythology and folklore, and not historical fact.

[Humblus, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humblus)

> The standing on stones in connection with the choosing a king is a motive known from other Scandinavian sources. It occurs both in Chronicon Lethrense and Olaus Magnus's Swedish history.

**Corineus**

There are however depictions of ancient legendary/mythological kings standing on standing stones at election, such as Corineus.

[Corineus, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corineus)

> Corineus, in medieval British legend, was a prodigious warrior, a fighter of giants, and the eponymous founder of Cornwall.

[Corineus by F W Fairholt FSA - Fairholt, F W (1859), Gog and Magog: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corineus#/media/File:Corineus_the_Giant_in_Guildhall_1859.png)
[image: One of two wooden figures displayed in the Guildhall in London, carved by Captain Richard Saunders in 1709, replacing earlier wicker and pasteboard effigies which were traditionally carried in the Lord Mayor's Show. They represented Gogmagog and Corineus, but were later known as Gog and Magog. Both figures were destroyed during the London Blitz in 1940; new figures were carved in 1953.]

**Is the practise of standing on stones at election consigned to mythology and folklore?**

So my question is, is this practise consigned to mythology and folklore, or is there actual archaeological or historical reasons to believe this practise may actually be factual?